# How to isolate snapshot volumes with btrfs?

Tags: btrfs, snapshot

If I create a snapshot of root with: `btrfs subvolume snapshot -r / /snapshot-$(date +%s)`

I can then see this snapshot with `ls /`

How do I make snapshots that are **isolated from the volume that they were created for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how I opted to do this was by editing the root subvolume (0):

1. Mount the root subvolume: `mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=0 /dev/sdXX /mnt`
2. Created the snapshot subvolume: `cd /mnt; btrfs subvolume create @snapshots`

Did a preliminary `ls /` and noticed I didn't see the subvolume; great, now onto next step; a test!

To create *isolated* snapshots that aren't visible from the original subvolume mount the created subvolume (`@snapshot`), create the snapshot, and then unmount it.

1. Mount the snapshot subvolume; get the subvolume ID with `btrfs subvolume list /` and then mount it: `mount -t btrfs -o subvolid=<id> /dev/sdXX /mnt`
2. Create the snapshot of `/` into `/mnt` with: `btrfs subvolume snapshot -r / /mnt/snapshot_$(date +%s)`